# Is SMS the only way to register with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, sms

I don't have a cell phone, but Google App Engine needs an SMS message to verify the account. Is there another way to complete the registration?

I'm surprised they don't use a Gmail account to do this.

---

Edit : Google created one for me, problem solved.

Comment: I am quite happy they require SMS.  I don't want app engine to be full of spammers,warez peddlers, and people just looking to abuse the free quota by having 1000's of accounts.  walmart sells no contract cell phones for $10.  that's enough to keep out the spammers but should not be an impediment to a serious developer.  I'd rather the app engine team spend their time making app engine better than worry about the tiny intersection of potential users who want to develop web apps but don't have any access to a sms device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  If you don't have a way to receive SMS, you can fill out the [SMS issues form](https://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues) to have an account created for you.

Comment: This is the official answer - see the FAQ: http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/sms.html

Answer (score 3):

You could sign up with any **web based sms service** that enables you to receive sms via virtual phone numbers.

The first one i found that offers a free trial was [**esendex.co.uk**](http://www.esendex.co.uk/Services/Web-SMS).

But quick [**search**](http://www.google.de/search?q=receive+web+sms+online) will get you many more.

Or you could just ask somebody to lend you his phone for 5min in ... receiving sms is free after all.

Comment: Good idea, but it failed when I tried to register. I couldn't find any other sites that would provide a free number (needed for Google).

Answer (score 1):

They probably don't use Gmail because there are too many Gmail accounts in the wild.  Gmail now requires verification by SMS or a voice call, but it didn't always.  App Engine is limited to SMS only (no automated voice call option).

You probably have a friend whose cell phone you can use.

Comment: I thought of that too, but :
<1> Does it cost to receive SMS on my friend's phone ?
<2> Will Google send SMS to someone else to verify my Google App ?
<3> I still don't understand why Google needs SMS, why not my email account like Yahoo Email to verify, if I can use a friend's phone, what's Google's point ? I guess they want to collect cell phone numbers for their other uses.

Comment: 1. For most plans it should only cost a few cents (obviously check first). 2. Google has no way of knowing you're using a friend's phone.  They won't use the number except for verification (http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/sms.html#number) .

Comment: @Frank: (3), because they don't want to give away one GAE account per Yahoo email address in the world, but they're happy to give away one (or a limited number, I don't know) per cellphone number. Don't pick a friend who's likely ever to want their own GAE account, because they might not be able to get one to the same number. You'd have to ask them for the exact thinking, but basically it's easier to get hold of 1000 email addresses than to get hold of 1000 cellphones. Google is giving you quite a lot of free stuff with a GAE account.

Comment: @Steve : Thanks for the info, I can understand that now, but I'm stuck without a cell phone, I wish Google can make some exceptions for someone without a cell phone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Google have instigated quite strong protection on new gmail accounts, at least here in the UK @googlemail.co.uk addresses require SMS confirmation as well.

Comment: Here in Brazil is required as well. name@gmail.com