# Verification SMS - Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a problem regarding Google App Engine. I wanted to create a new application and SMS verification code is required. I entered my phone number correctly, but i received nothing !!! ... again and again until "You have sent too many SMS verification messages." and yet i got nothing.

I came by this question and tried it, but still not working: 
[Is SMS the only way to register with Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684751/is-sms-the-only-way-to-register-with-google-app-engine)

**Does anyone know what can i do to solve this problem ?**

Thanks,

Samer Samy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you fill out the [SMS issues form](https://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues)?

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems too, only I wanted it to call my phone. I realized that I wasn't clicking the 'call me' radio option. Once I did that, it called right away.

Answer (score 0):

Please enter a phone number that has not been used. It worked for me.